# why lld-link.exe is needed when building Qt 6.1.2 examples?

Tags: qt, qt6

I am trying to build Qt's analogclock example using MSVC2019 kit, however Qt Creator complains as below. I am curious why lld-link.exe is needed, while I want to use MSVC2019 as compiler.

What sounds interesting to me is that in Makefile.Debug, CC and CXX is set to clang-cl.

I might some misunderstanding how MSVC2019 is used by Qt Creator / Qt Examples.

Any comment is much appreciate it.

**Kit configurations**

[image]

**Tools > Options > Kit > Kits**
[image]

**Tools > Options > Kit > Compilers**
[image]

**Compile Output**

```
01:49:57: Running steps for project analogclock...
01:49:57: Starting: "C:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\bin\qmake.exe" C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-6.1.2\widgets\widgets\analogclock\analogclock.pro -spec win32-clang-msvc "CONFIG+=debug"
01:49:57: The process "C:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
01:49:57: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" -f C:/Qt/Examples/Qt-6.1.2/widgets/widgets/build-analogclock-Desktop_Qt_6_1_2_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/Makefile qmake_all

jom 1.1.3 - empower your cores

01:49:57: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited normally.
01:49:57: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
    clang-cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -Wno-microsoft-enum-value -fms-compatibility-version=19.29.30038 -Zi -MDd -std:c++17 -utf-8 -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -EHsc /Fddebug\analogclock.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -DWIN64 -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\analogclock -I. -IC:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\include -IC:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -IC:/VulkanSDK/1.0.51.0/Include -IC:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\mkspecs\win32-clang-msvc -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\MIKE-~1\AppData\Local\Temp\analogclock.obj.3280.0.jom
    clang-cl -BxC:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\bin\qmake.exe -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -Wno-microsoft-enum-value -fms-compatibility-version=19.29.30038 -Zi -MDd -std:c++17 -utf-8 -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -E C:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\mkspecs\features\data\dummy.cpp 2>NUL >debug\moc_predefs.h
    C:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -DWIN64 -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB --compiler-flavor=msvc --include C:/Qt/Examples/Qt-6.1.2/widgets/widgets/build-analogclock-Desktop_Qt_6_1_2_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/debug/moc_predefs.h -IC:/Qt/6.1.2/msvc2019_64/mkspecs/win32-clang-msvc -IC:/Qt/Examples/Qt-6.1.2/widgets/widgets/analogclock -IC:/Qt/6.1.2/msvc2019_64/include -IC:/Qt/6.1.2/msvc2019_64/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/6.1.2/msvc2019_64/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/6.1.2/msvc2019_64/include/QtCore -I. -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\ATLMFC\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" ..\analogclock\analogclock.h -o debug\moc_analogclock.cpp
    clang-cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -Wno-microsoft-enum-value -fms-compatibility-version=19.29.30038 -Zi -MDd -std:c++17 -utf-8 -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -EHsc /Fddebug\analogclock.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -DWIN64 -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\analogclock -I. -IC:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\include -IC:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -IC:/VulkanSDK/1.0.51.0/Include -IC:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\mkspecs\win32-clang-msvc -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\MIKE-~1\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.3280.63.jom
    clang-cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -Wno-microsoft-enum-value -fms-compatibility-version=19.29.30038 -Zi -MDd -std:c++17 -utf-8 -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -EHsc /Fddebug\analogclock.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -DWIN64 -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\analogclock -I. -IC:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\include -IC:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -IC:/VulkanSDK/1.0.51.0/Include -IC:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\mkspecs\win32-clang-msvc -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\MIKE-~1\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_analogclock.obj.3280.344.jom
    lld-link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:debug\analogclock.exe @C:\Users\MIKE-~1\AppData\Local\Temp\analogclock.exe.3280.2329.jom
'lld-link' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
jom: C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-6.1.2\widgets\widgets\build-analogclock-Desktop_Qt_6_1_2_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\analogclock.exe] Error 1
jom: C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-6.1.2\widgets\widgets\build-analogclock-Desktop_Qt_6_1_2_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
01:50:00: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project analogclock (kit: Desktop Qt 6.1.2 MSVC2019 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
01:50:00: Elapsed time: 00:03.
```

Makefile.DEBUG

```
#############################################################################
# Makefile for building: analogclock
# Generated by qmake (3.1) (Qt 6.1.2)
# Project:  ..\analogclock\analogclock.pro
# Template: app
#############################################################################

MAKEFILE      = Makefile.Debug

EQ            = =

####### Compiler, tools and options

CC            = clang-cl
CXX           = clang-cl
DEFINES       = -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -DWIN64 -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB
CFLAGS        = -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -Wno-microsoft-enum-value -fms-compatibility-version=19.29.30038 -Zi -MDd -utf-8 -W3 /Fddebug\analogclock.vc.pdb $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -Wno-microsoft-enum-value -fms-compatibility-version=19.29.30038 -Zi -MDd -std:c++17 -utf-8 -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -EHsc /Fddebug\analogclock.vc.pdb $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I..\analogclock -I. -IC:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\include -IC:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -IC:/VulkanSDK/1.0.51.0/Include -IC:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\mkspecs\win32-clang-msvc 
LINKER        = lld-link
```

Comment: The Qt Kit you're using is (for some reason) configured to use clang instead of just MSVC compiler directly.  You can look at the Qt Creator Tools -> Options -> Kits page (or the "Manage Kits" button in your screenshot) to see how the kit is actually set up and which compiler it's set to use (you can also change it from there).  If still lost then perhaps post screenshots of the Kits and Compilers setup pages. The project's Build Settings aren't very informative in this case.

Comment: @MaximPaperno I added Tools > Options > Kit > Kits/Compilers, though I still don't understand why the issue exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I needed to add support for Clang/LLVM to my VS2019 installation.

Follow the instructions discussed below:

[Clang/LLVM Support in Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/clang-llvm-support-in-visual-studio/)

> On Windows, it’s easy to install the Clang tools. Just grab the “Clang
> compiler for Windows,” an optional component of the “Desktop
> development with C++” workload. This will install everything you need
> to develop with Clang on Windows.

And here is how I did it through Visual Studio Installer

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. It resolve build with new QtCreator 5 and msvc compiller.

Comment: Does this properly fix the original (broken) "Desktop Qt6.1.2 MSVC2019 64bit" Qt Kit as shown in the original question?  Or does that kit still use the compiler from Qt/Tools directory? Just because `lld-link` is now in the PATH doesn't mean the whole kit is set up correctly.  Personally I'd make sure the Qt kit is using all components (compiler, linker, etc) from the same LLVM/Clang version/package (the one VSI installed, presumably). Or if QtCreator auto-detected the new, full LLVM install and created a kit from it, that would be the one to use IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

As per my comment on the question, the Qt Kit auto-detected set up for MSVC2019 seems to use the wrong compiler. Though it's certainly possible to use a LLVM (clang) compiler on Windows, I've personally only done this with "official" LLVM distributions (not whatever is included with MSVC).

Anyway, one way to resolve this would be to add the correct Kit manually. The simplest way should be (as per screenshots in the question) to:

1. In the Kit setup, select the existing `Desktop Qt6.1.2 MSVC2019 64bit` Kit.
2. Use the `Clone` button to create a copy of it, then select the copy from the list.
3. In the copy, just change the two Compiler options to use `Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 16.10.31424.327 (amd64)` (it's OK that they both say "C++" in the name even though one of them is for the "C" compiler).
4. Adjust the kit names so you know which is which in the project settings. Maybe change the broken auto-detected Kit name to include "LLVM" or "broken" or some such to distinguish it. "OK" out of the options dialog.
5. Now in the Project Build Settings you will be able to select the newly added Kit. Just click on it to enable it. You may also want to disable the broken kit (r-click on the kit name for a menu).

Keep in mind that Qt 6.1 is not feature complete yet (not everything from 5.x has been ported), though the included examples should work. Upcoming 6.2 release should be more complete, but still breaks lots of 5.x stuff. To try a more mature version with greater backwards compatibility with most existing Qt projects, use 5.12.x or 5.15.x versions.

Comment: That is a good workaround, but how can I activate / benefit from "Default LLVM 64 bit based on MSVC2019" ... ???

Comment: @MikeITExpert I don't know why that "compiler" is even in the list of auto-detected ones (probably a bug). I have it in my QtC config also, after I installed MSVC 2019. But looking at its details (in Compilers setup), it's pretty messed up -- using compiler binary which was installed with QtC (for code parsing), and a MSVC init command which is for MSVC compiler (not clang). I don't see how that would ever work, but maybe I'm missing something. If you really want LLVM (for some reason), d-load and install the -win64 package from https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-12.0.1